# phpinfo() in magento2

Tags: magento2, php

I created a `phpinfo.php` page in my Magento2 project but when I try to access it via URL it shows a 404 page.

It's set up here in the magento root:

```
|-Magento2
|-----<other folders etc.>
|-----phpinfo.php
```

url I try to go to: `site.local/phpinfo.php` - returns 404

I tried running all the commands but still 404s.. is it something with routing that's preventing me from just accessing a file normally?

**Edit:** my `phpinfo` code:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
```

Comment: Can you please add your code here

Comment: are you using nginx?

Comment: @trey Bake  !!, Give a try to adding index.php after your domain. Like 

`http://site.local/index.php/phpinfo.php` If still not work than rename .htaccess than check.

Comment: site.local this runs your magento2 website correctly? What is the document root of your magento2 instance?

Comment: @WebDeveloper lemme give it a go :)

Comment: @SukumarGorai yeah everything works - and `/var/www/site`

Comment: @WebDeveloper did nada :/

Comment: So your site is running on root not in pub?

Comment: @SukumarGorai ah it is pub^^

Comment: Then place the phpinfo.php into the pub directory and run the above url.

Comment: made it work: .htaccess -> .htaccessOLD and mv file into pub - url is `http://site.local/phpinfo.php`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87175/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-treybake).

Comment: @WebDeveloper not sure fully - but removing pub from url did

Comment: you can also add your answer below !!

Comment: @WebDeveloper nah will VTC - it's a typo issue haha

Answer (score 5):

As [Jaimie Dijstra](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/22591/jaimie-dijstra) mentioned, your `phpinfo.php` file has to be placed inside the `<magento_root>/pub`  directory.

However, if you are using `Nginx` as a webserver, you also have to edit the `<magnto_root>/nginx.conf` file (I assume you include the `<magento_root>/nginx.conf` file in your server configuration as [advised by Magento](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/nginx.html#configure-nginx-ubuntu)).
Search for

```
# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ ^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check)\.php$ {
```

and add `phpinfo` as follows

```
# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ ^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check|phpinfo)\.php$ {
```

After you have saved the file, you have to restart your Nginx service.

Now you should be able to access the phpinfo page `your.magento.domain/phpinfo.php`.

Comment: Big up you, worked a treat, everyone should be aware that placing in the `pub/` folder **and** restarting Nginx are important notes though!

Answer (score 2):

I tried it on my instance and it works nicely. I added the file in the root folder and when calling it in the browser it shows my PHP info.
Make sure you disable the cache (especially full page cache). Maybe the page is cached from a previous request.
Also if you are on nginx where .htaccess has no effect, maybe you have a rule configured that redirects everything to `index.php` and Magento does not find the info page.

Comment: yeah was my bad - forgot I set docroot to pub/ so obviously pub/phpinfo.php 404s

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2 the file to load on the front end (i.e. mywebsite.com/phpinfo.php), the php file needs to go in the pub folder of the magento install. Simple as this.